# How to gradually increase the rate of something?

Tags: java, loops, sprite, increment

I'm creating a 2d zombie shooter game and I'm trying to think of a good way to gradually increase the rate of which zombies are created.

I create a zombie with the following code.

```
    public void createZombies(){

    int direction = new Random().nextInt(4);

    if (direction == 0) {
        // spawn from top
        zombies.add(new Zombie(new Random().nextInt(1120), new Random()
                .nextInt(1)));
    }
    if (direction == 1) {
        // spawn from left
        zombies.add(new Zombie(new Random().nextInt(1), new Random()
                .nextInt(640)));
    }
    if (direction == 2) {
        // spawn from bottom
        zombies.add(new Zombie(new Random().nextInt(1120), 640));
    }
    if (direction == 3) {
        // spawn from right
        zombies.add(new Zombie(1120, new Random().nextInt(640)));
    }


}
```

I basically want to call that method from my main  method (which runs continuously). I thought of maybe using modular and do something like:

```
    int x = 1;
    if(x  % 1000 == 0){
        createZombies();
    }

    x++;
```

but that seems messy - and it doesnt change how frequently they are created.

I'm just a bit stumped at finding a good way to do this - and surprisingly I couldn't find anything useful on here either.
So if anybody can point out a good idea to do this it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is the current rate for your zombies, I don't get it?

Comment: Does your game keep score or keep track of how long the person is playing?

Answer (score 1):

Guava has a [RateLimiter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) which may be useful for your use case. In particular, you could do something like:

```
//initially, create one zombie every 10 seconds
final RateLimiter zombieRate = RateLimiter.create(0.1);
Runnable increaseRate = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        //increase rate by 20%
        zombieRate.setRate(zombieRate.getRate() * 1.2);
    }
};

//then increase the rate every minute
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(increaseRate, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Your Zombie creation then becomes:

```
while (true) {
    zombieRate.acquire();
    createZombie();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decrease each time the period between zombie creations:

```
    int x = 1;
    int tau = 1000;

    if(x  % tau == 0){
        createZombies();
    }

    x++;
    tau = tau > 0 ? --tau : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the "velocity" of zomby creation in respect to time elapsed.

```
double velocity=0.5; //every 2ms 1 zomby
long latestCreation = System.currentTimeMillis();
double rest = 0;

public synchronized void createZombies() {
   double number=velocity * (System.currentTimeMillis() - latestCreation) + rest;
   latestCreation = System.currentTimeMillis()

   int n = Math.round(number);
   rest = number - n; //n° of partial zomby
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) createZomby();
}
```

from your thread or when you prefer call createZombies().

Unfortunatly you cannot know when the thread will be really executed then you have to define a function time dependent. The var "rest" is an optimization when the number will return some decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
       float maxZombieRate = 0.8; //for example
       float zombieRate = 0.05;
       while(zombieRate<=maxZombieRate){ //you could have a timer too
            if(Math.random <= zombieRate){ //Math.random returns values between 0 and 1
                createZombies(); //
                zombieRate+=0.05; //increase in 5% the probability of run createZombies()
            }
        }
```